# C++ ensuring thread safety of atomic shared pointers

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm, data-structures, shared-ptr

## Intro

I am by no means an expert on algorithms or data structures. However, recently I had the need for a concurrent priority queue. I started with a naive single mutex version which was not performant enough. So, now I am building a lock-free skip-list based priority queue in C++20.

So far, the queue works just fine even in multi-producer multi-consumer tests. However, the problem I have is of course memory reclamation. For this purpose, I am using my own version of shared pointers as a way to reference count and delete nodes that are no longer used/needed. This shared pointer implementation is supposed to be atomic, though currently it has issues.

In my queue, popping/removing is lazy. Popping a node atomically "marks" all its connections as "to be removed". On a subsequent access that traverses a marked connection, that connection can actually become severed (by connecting the predecessor to the successor directly, droping the current node from in between, also atomically). Once all connections have been severed, and I have no references to the node, the node can now be deleted from memory.

## Implementation

Based on the above, I have two implementations for the shared pointer. One that supports atomic marking for use in the data structure storage, and one that doesn't support marking, for other use throughout the algorithm.

Here is the code:

```cpp
#ifndef __CSLPQ_MARKEDPOINTER_HPP__
#define __CSLPQ_MARKEDPOINTER_HPP__

#include <cstdint>
#include <atomic>

namespace CSLPQ
{
    template<typename T>
    class MarkedSharedPointer;

    template<typename T>
    class alignas(16) SharedPointer
    {
        private:
            std::atomic<uint64_t>* reference_count;         // A pointer to the atomic ref counter
            T* pointer;                         // The actual data pointer

            void Release()
            {
                if (this->reference_count)
                {
                    auto count = this->reference_count->fetch_sub(1);
                    if (count == 1)
                    {
                        delete this->reference_count;
                        delete this->pointer;
                        this->reference_count = 0;
                        this->pointer = 0;
                    }
                }
            }

        public:
            explicit SharedPointer(T* pointer = nullptr) : reference_count(nullptr), pointer(pointer)
            {
                if (pointer)
                {
                    this->reference_count = new std::atomic<uint64_t>(1);
                }
            }

        protected:
            // Only for use by MarkedSharedPointer
            SharedPointer(T* pointer, std::atomic<uint64_t>* reference_count) : reference_count(reference_count),
                          pointer(pointer)
            {
                if (this->reference_count)
                {
                    this->reference_count->fetch_add(1);
                }
            }

        public:
            SharedPointer(const SharedPointer& other)
            {
                this->reference_count = other.reference_count;
                if (this->reference_count)
                {
                    this->reference_count->fetch_add(1);
                }
                this->pointer = other.pointer;
            }

            SharedPointer(SharedPointer&& other)
            {
                this->reference_count = other.reference_count;
                this->pointer = other.pointer;
                other.reference_count = nullptr;
                other.pointer = nullptr;
            }

            SharedPointer& operator=(const SharedPointer& other)
            {
                if (this != &other)
                {
                    this->Release();
                    this->reference_count = other.reference_count;
                    if (this->reference_count)
                    {
                        this->reference_count->fetch_add(1);
                    }
                    this->pointer = other.pointer;
                }
                return *this;
            }

            SharedPointer& operator=(SharedPointer&& other)
            {
                if (this != &other)
                {
                    this->Release();
                    this->reference_count = other.reference_count;
                    this->pointer = other.pointer;
                    other.reference_count = nullptr;
                    other.pointer = nullptr;
                }
                return *this;
            }

            ~SharedPointer()
            {
                this->Release();
            }

            T& operator*()
            {
                return *this->pointer;
            }

            T* operator->()
            {
                return this->pointer;
            }

            explicit operator bool() const
            {
                return this->pointer != nullptr;
            }

            bool operator==(const SharedPointer& other) const
            {
                return this->pointer == other.pointer;
            }

            bool operator!=(const SharedPointer& other) const
            {
                return this->pointer != other.pointer;
            }

            friend class MarkedSharedPointer<T>;
    };

    template<typename T>
    class alignas(16) MarkedSharedPointer
    {
        private:
            std::atomic<uint64_t>* reference_count;         // A pointer to the atomic ref counter
            std::atomic<uintptr_t> pointer;             // The actual data pointer, with the most significant bit used as a flag, since modern x86_64 systems never use it.

            static const uintptr_t mask = (uintptr_t)1 << ((sizeof(uintptr_t) * 8) - 1);

            void Release()
            {
                if (this->reference_count)
                {
                    auto count = this->reference_count->fetch_sub(1);
                    if (count == 1)
                    {
                        uintptr_t val = this->pointer.load();
                        val &= ~MarkedSharedPointer::mask;
                        T* ptr = (T*)val;
                        this->pointer.store(0);
                        delete this->reference_count;
                        this->reference_count = 0;
                        delete ptr;
                    }
                }
            }

        public:
            explicit MarkedSharedPointer(T* pointer = nullptr, bool marked = false) : reference_count(nullptr),
                                         pointer((uintptr_t)pointer)
            {
                if (pointer)
                {
                    this->reference_count = new std::atomic<uint64_t>(1);
                    if (marked)
                    {
                        // Set the MSB
                        auto val = (uintptr_t) pointer;
                        val |= MarkedSharedPointer::mask;
                        this->pointer.store((val));
                    }
                }
            }

            MarkedSharedPointer(const MarkedSharedPointer& other)
            {
                this->reference_count = other.reference_count;
                if (this->reference_count)
                {
                    this->reference_count->fetch_add(1);
                }
                this->pointer.store(other.pointer.load());
            }

            MarkedSharedPointer(MarkedSharedPointer&& other)
            {
                this->reference_count = other.reference_count;
                this->pointer.store(other.pointer.load());
                other.reference_count = nullptr;
                other.pointer.store(0);
            }

            MarkedSharedPointer(const SharedPointer<T>& other)
            {
                this->reference_count = other.reference_count;
                if (this->reference_count)
                {
                    this->reference_count->fetch_add(1);
                }
                this->pointer.store((uintptr_t)other.pointer);
            }

            MarkedSharedPointer(SharedPointer<T>&& other)
            {
                this->reference_count = other.reference_count;
                this->pointer.store((uintptr_t)other.pointer);
                other.reference_count = nullptr;
                other.pointer = nullptr;
            }

            MarkedSharedPointer& operator=(const MarkedSharedPointer& other)
            {
                if (this != &other)
                {
                    this->Release();
                    this->reference_count = other.reference_count;
                    if (this->reference_count)
                    {
                        this->reference_count->fetch_add(1);
                    }
                    this->pointer.store(other.pointer.load());
                }
                return *this;
            }

            MarkedSharedPointer& operator=(MarkedSharedPointer&& other) noexcept
            {
                if (this != &other)
                {
                    this->Release();
                    this->reference_count = other.reference_count;
                    this->pointer.store(other.pointer.load());
                    other.reference_count = nullptr;
                    other.pointer.store(0);
                }
                return *this;
            }

            MarkedSharedPointer& operator=(const SharedPointer<T>& other)
            {
                this->Release();
                this->reference_count = other.reference_count;
                if (this->reference_count)
                {
                    this->reference_count->fetch_add(1);
                }
                this->pointer.store((uintptr_t)other.pointer);
                return *this;
            }

            MarkedSharedPointer& operator=(SharedPointer<T>&& other) noexcept
            {
                if (this != &other)
                {
                    this->Release();
                    this->reference_count = other.reference_count;
                    this->pointer.store((uintptr_t)other.pointer);
                    other.reference_count = nullptr;
                    other.pointer = nullptr;
                }
                return *this;
            }

            ~MarkedSharedPointer()
            {
                this->Release();
            }

            bool IsMarked() const
            {
                uintptr_t val = this->pointer.load();
                return val & MarkedSharedPointer::mask;
            }

            SharedPointer<T> GetPointer() const
            {
                uintptr_t val = this->pointer.load();
                val &= ~MarkedSharedPointer::mask;
                auto sp = SharedPointer<T>((T*)val, this->reference_count);
                return sp;
            }

            std::pair<SharedPointer<T>, bool> GetPointerAndMark() const
            {
                uintptr_t val = this->pointer.load();
                T* ptr = (T*)(val & ~MarkedSharedPointer::mask);
                auto sp = SharedPointer<T>(ptr, this->reference_count);
                bool mark = val & MarkedSharedPointer::mask;
                return std::make_pair(sp, mark);
            }

            T& operator*() const
            {
                uintptr_t val = this->pointer.load();
                val &= ~MarkedSharedPointer::mask;
                return *(T*)val;
            }

            T* operator->() const
            {
                uintptr_t val = this->pointer.load();
                val &= ~MarkedSharedPointer::mask;
                return (T*)val;
            }

            explicit operator bool() const
            {
                uintptr_t val = this->pointer.load();
                val &= ~MarkedSharedPointer::mask;
                return (T*)val != nullptr;
            }

            bool operator==(const MarkedSharedPointer& other) const
            {
                uintptr_t val = this->pointer.load();
                val &= ~MarkedSharedPointer::mask;
                uintptr_t other_val = other.pointer.load();
                other_val &= ~MarkedSharedPointer::mask;
                return val == other_val;
            }

            bool operator!=(const MarkedSharedPointer& other) const
            {
                uintptr_t val = this->pointer.load();
                val &= ~MarkedSharedPointer::mask;
                uintptr_t other_val = other.pointer.load();
                other_val &= ~MarkedSharedPointer::mask;
                return val != other_val;
            }

            void SetMark()
            {
                // Do using fetch or
                this->pointer.fetch_or(MarkedSharedPointer::mask);
            }

            bool TestAndSetMark(SharedPointer<T>& expected)
            {
                uintptr_t val = (uintptr_t)expected.pointer;
                val &= ~MarkedSharedPointer::mask;
                uintptr_t new_val = (uintptr_t)expected.pointer;
                new_val |= MarkedSharedPointer::mask;
                return this->pointer.compare_exchange_strong(val, new_val);
            }

            bool CompareExchange(SharedPointer<T>& old_value, SharedPointer<T>& new_value)
            {
                // Register old ref pointer and data pointer, so we can delete them on success
                std::atomic<uint64_t>* old_ref_count = old_value.reference_count;
                T* old_ptr = old_value.pointer;

                // CAS the entire shared pointer
                bool success = false;
                __asm__ __volatile__
                (
                    "lock cmpxchg16b %1\n\t"
                    "setz %0"
                    : "=q" (success),
                      "+m" (*this),
                      "+d" (old_value.pointer),
                      "+a" (old_value.reference_count)
                    : "c" (new_value.pointer),
                      "b" (new_value.reference_count)
                    : "cc", "memory"
                );

                if (success)
                {
                    // Decrement the old ref count
                    if (old_ref_count)
                    {
                        auto count = old_ref_count->fetch_sub(1);
                        if (count == 1)
                        {
                            delete old_ref_count;
                            delete old_ptr;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return success;
            }
    };
}

#endif // __CSLPQ_MARKEDPOINTER_HPP__
```

## Issue

This seems to work fine in single thread situations. I can also see that the reference counting works as expected in multi-thread situations. However, occasionally I run into the following issue:

1. This is the last shared pointer instance of a node, so reference count = 1.
2. Thread 1 starts using the pointer member functions. e.g., `GetPointer` from the `MarkedSharedPointer`.
3. Thread 2 deletes the last shared pointer instance (for example, by removing it from the skip list), thus destructing it, triggering its `Release` function and deleting both the node it points to as well as its reference counter.
4. Thread 1 continues its execution of the function `GetPointer`. But because of the previous point, it accesses memory that has now been deleted, possibly causing a segmentation fault.

I have been at this for quite a while and I am still unsure of how to go about fixing it. I have thought about using mutexes in the shared pointers. But even then, the mutex would be deleted when the last `Release` and the same issue would happen. I also thought about making the algorithm explicitly check the shared pointer count and delete the associated nodes, but there is still no guarantee that another thread won't try to access while the delete is happenning.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Within your queue implementation are you assigning new values to your shared_ptr or only creating them (when queuing) and then using them? The control block of std::shared_ptr is threadsafe already so no need to make your std::shared_ptr atomic if you do not reassign values to the shared_ptr.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that contain two consecutive underscores (`__CSLPQ_MARKEDPOINTER_HPP__`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer as such I'm afraid, merely some observations. Apologies in advance if I'm wide of the mark.

Regarding a single mutex not being performant enough, depending on the OS this might indicate the potential for disappointment in the future. If you're using Linux, a mutex take boils down to an atomic operation (much as if you'd programmed to use an atomic variable instead of a mutex) if there is no contention for the mutex. It'll spin for a short while if there is contention, and only as a last resort will the thread end up on the wait queue.

So, if you were having too much contention on the mutex, you might end up with too much contention with an atomic too. Atomics are lockless only in the sense that whatever locking that happens is down in the micro-electronic level (there has to be some locking down there, other atomic operations such as CAS won't work). Multiple contenders for the same thing are still queued up and forced to wait, there's still all the same memory fences, etc.

Also, lazy removing. The slow part of deleting an object is generally held to be the freeing up of memory - the `delete`. However, in modern C/C++ implementations memory allocators tend to be a lot smarter than simply passing every `new` and `delete` through to the OS, they're often managing a pool of memory by themselves, only bothering the OS as and when they need more or find they have an excess. So, this means that even if your code is calling new / delete an awful lot, it doesn't mean that this is resulting in a lot of slow memory allocations by the OS. Again, this tends to be OS specific (because code gets built against the default libraries), but not necessarily so.

I don't know about C++20, C++11, but back in the days when `shared_ptr` and its like were provided by Boost, there were symbols one could define that would control exactly how Boost implemented locking for smart points. For example, if your application was single threaded you could set the right symbol that stripped out any locking from smart pointers. If you wanted to force it to use mutexes, you could do that, and it would use atomics too (if memory serves).

I suppose where I'm headed is that, if you're on Linux using the standard libraries, used standard smart pointers in C++, and just used `new` and `delete` in the most naive / ASAP manner (or, just left smart pointers to do that for you), you'll end up with something that's pretty close to optimal on the hardware you've got underneath you. There may be some performance gains to be had from a highly optimised hand-crafted application specific implementation, but the performance gain might be disappointing.

Comment: As for locks vs atomics, you are absolutely correct. The improvement here does not come from the switch from mutexes to atomics, but rather that the mutex was coarse grained. One for the entire queue, atomics are fine grained. So should be much less contention.

Comment: Also, the reason I made my own was not performance. I just wanted a shared pointer that I can atomically mark. and shared_ptr wouldn;t allow that. Once I had the marked version, I couldn't connect it to shared_ptr so had to create my own as well.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the implementation of `MarkedSharedPointer` is inherently bugged. The object isn't atomic. It consists of two separate atomic objects, so just by doing a couple of operations from multiple-threads it is easy to break their co-dependence, i.e., obtain an instance of `MarkedSharedPointer` that has reference counter from one object while pointing to another.

Instead, you can write `std::atomic<PairOfPointerAndReferenceCounter>`, but you'll have to use `compare_exchange_weak/strong` for manipulations like `fetch_sub/fetch_add`.

The second problem is in the example that you described; you poorly use the shared pointer. You use the same shared pointer instance from two different threads which is straight up a terrible idea. Each thread ought to have its own instance of the shared pointer to properly manage its lifetime. One normally forwards the shared pointers at the construction of the thread or via a mutex during operation which is why it is rare to see someone try to implement or use an atomic shared pointer - as it is an edge case.

Comment: I understand your point about the first half. I guess I can make modifications to address these. However, it is still possible even with making these atomic that a thread would try to do a CAS on already removed memory. I still don't know how to prevent that.

Comment: As for the second half, I HAVE to use from multiple thread. The queue itself has these pointers and multiple threads can access the queue together. Maybe if I followed your advice about the first half it would be possible to create copies of these pointers before I operate on them, but that still leaves the copying from dead memory issue.

Comment: @mewais you must not use a shared pointer in a thread while another thread deletes the instance. That's straight up data race and UB. Your only option is to copy the shared pointer and check if it still valid, and only then attempt an execution.

Comment: How do I check if it still valid then? I would have a pointer to something that may or may not be deleted. How would I know?

Comment: @mewais after fixing the issue of atomicity, you ought to ensure that threads that tried to copy the shared pointer but were too late, will definitely get an empty shared pointer. That's one of the requirement for proper atomicity.